# Best way to implement this box / table design in Adobe Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am sorry about asking such a newbie question but I am wondering if Adobe Indesign has any easy method of making the box that is on the top of the page that I posted below (With the numbers on top and bottom and text inside of it). I have to make a page similar to this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Set the text using tabs and paragraph returns between where the table cells are. Then highlight the text and choose Table > Convert Text to Table. Click okay.

From this point it's a matter of adjusting the table. There are many options. You may want to review the Indesign help files regarding tables.

Comment: I decided to do that but create a table in the textbox first and then entering the text.